# Использование внешних шрифтов PySide2

Tags: css, python, pyside2, ttf

Как я могу использовать шрифты в стилях программы на PySide2, которые не установлены на комп, а просто находятся в папке с проектом в виде файла? Например Roboto.ttf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> static PySide2.QtGui.QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont(fileName)
>
> Загружает шрифт из файла, указанного в fileName, и делает его доступным для приложения.
> Возвращается идентификатор, который можно использовать для повторного удаления шрифта
> с помощью removeApplicationFont() или для получения списка фамилий, содержащихся в шрифте.

```
import glob
import os
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import QFontDatabase, QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QWidget, QGridLayout


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
names = []

for path in glob.glob("D:/_Qt/Python-Examples/_PyQt5/Font/Fonts/Roboto/*.ttf"):
    names.append(os.path.basename(path.replace(".ttf", "")).replace("-", ""))
    fid = QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont(os.path.abspath(path))

w = QWidget()
w.setWindowTitle("Roboto Fonts")
layout = QGridLayout(w)

for row in range(4):
    for col in range(4):
        layout.addWidget(QLabel(names[row * 4 + col],
                                font=QFont(names[row * 4 + col], 16)),    # , 26)),
                         row, col, 1, 1)

w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Например, так:

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
QtGui.QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont('путь/к/шрифту')